# Структура БД. Вывксти информацию о территории

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет.

У меня возникли сложности с выполнением задания. Опишу вкратце что требуется сделать.

Есть база данных с данными. Пример структуры привожу ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На странице есть три поля:

```
1. Список областей
2. Список городов
3. Список районов
```

Мне нужно в эти три списка подгрузить соответствующие данные. Для областей - области, для городов - города и тд.

Но вот в чём проблема. В бд данные введены в одно поле, как видно на картинке это **ter_address** - с.Верхня Кутузовка (Ізобільнянська сільрада), м.Алушта, Автономна Республіка Крим.

У меня есть идея сделать так. Взять данные из поля **ter_address** и разбить эту строку по запятой, чтобы получилось три значения. (Как видно, в строке данные идут по порядку, сначала город -> район -> область). И потом занести эти значения в каждый список.

Не понимаю для чего нужны остальные столбцы в таблице. Менять структуру таблицы запрещено.

Может у кого-то есть идеи? Всем спасибо за помощь :)

Comment: "...Не понимаю для чего нужны остальные столбцы в таблице..." - я думаю, что на Форуме тоже будут в полном недоумении. Единственный человек, кто это понимает, - ИМХО, Ваш преподаватель

Comment: Это точно :)

Ну, а что можно сделать с заполнением списков?

Comment: Сразу нарушение первой нормальной формы и запрет изменять структуру таблицы - красота. Хороший пример того, как проектировать не надо. Ну будем надеяться, что это сделано осознанно. А так да, разбивайте на части по запятой и выводите через `DISTINCT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(...)`. Вот пример, если надо: https://oracleplsql.ru/mysql-function-substring_index.html

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь.